# How do you return all the elements in a list of lists? (PLT Scheme)

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket

For example,
If the input is:
(list (list 1) (list 2) (list 3))
Output will be:
(list 1 2 3)

Why doesn't this code work?

```
(define (listoutput mylist)
  (cond
    [(empty? mylist) empty]
    [(cons? mylist) (append (list (first list)) (listoutput (rest mylist)))]))

(check-expect (listoutput (list (list 1) (list 2) (list 3)))
              (list 1 2 3)
```

Comment: Perhaps to point out the obvious, `check-expect` is missing a close-paren.

Answer (score 2):

You're actually fairly close. Here are some questions that might help:

What's the contract/signature of `listoutput`?

What's the contract/signature of `append`?

Also, I recommend building your examples simplest first, each example building on the previous ones. For example,

```
(check-expect (listoutput empty)) ???)
(check-expect (listoutput (cons (list 1) empty)) ???)
```

If the first test passes but the second one fails, what does that imply about where the problem is, given the structure of the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
[(cons? mylist) (append (list (first list)) (listoutput (rest mylist)))]))
```

That line has two errors.  The most obvious is that it should be `(first mylist)` rather than `(first list)` (although I expect that you actually know that and mistyped it).  The second is that `(first mylist)` returns a list (since you are getting a list of lists), but then you wrap it with the `list` function before passing it to append.  As a result, in your example, you're not passing `(list 1)` to `append` the first time you call it, but rather `(list (list 1))`.  You should simply remove the `list` function from that expression.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the `flatten` procedure, try this:

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (cond ((empty? lst) null)
        ((not (list? lst)) (list lst))
        (else (append (flatten (first lst))
                      (flatten (rest lst))))))
```

You can test it:

```
(flatten  (list (list 1) (list 2) (list 3)))
> (1 2 3)
(flatten '(1 (2 (3)) (4)))
> (1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: Does flatten work for trees as well, or is there an equivalent?

Comment: A list of lists forms a tree, so you could say so. Why don't you give it a test?